# Riemann Zeta: $\zeta(1)$

Tags: contour-integration, riemann-zeta

When I perform a contour integral of

$\oint \dfrac{z}{e^z -1}~dz$

on a contour (as shown in [Fig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEpzC.jpg))

The integral has six parts and when done in this manner described [here](https://tinyurl.com/55ykhjd7)

I obtain:

$\zeta(1) = \int \limits_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{e^x - 1}~dx = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$

(along with a finite value for another divergent integral).

This feels like a $1=2$ result (which essentially means I am making a mistake in my assumptions) since $\zeta(1)$ should diverge.

Could somebody help me find the mistake in my assumptions?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Can you show more details of what you did?

Comment: This is certainly wrong.  $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{e^x-1} = +\infty$.  But since it is a 6 page calculation, I leave that up to you to check.  Since $1/(e^x-1)$ has an elementary antiderivative, you should be able to check each of the 6 results and see which ones are wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much :-) @AHusain, I have worked it out [here](https://tinyurl.com/55ykhjd7)  (pdf file)

Comment: @GEdgar, I completely agree.  Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out my error above.  My assumption that the area within the contour is simply connected is not correct as  $\dfrac{1}{e^z - 1} \approx \dfrac{1}{z}~~{\rm for}~~ z \ll 1$ and this causes the divergence.  For higher powers of $z$ (in the numerator) the region will be simply connected (and hence the method will hold for $\zeta(n)~~{\rm for}~~n>1$).

I would like to acknowledge my reference to this [source](https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/petersen.pdf).

Will close this post - thank you all for looking through and thanks to @AHusain and @GEdgar for your efforts.